# how the function influence.measures obtains actually the results in the columns dfb.1 , dfb.x, and dffi?

Tags: r, statistics

In some exam I have had, I was given this code and asked for finding the values marked with ??????
the code in the question was:

CODE

```r
attach (mydat)
mydat
lr1 = glm ( Y ~X , data = mydat , family = binomial ( link = logit ))
summary (lr1)
influence . measures (lr1)
```

OUTPUT

```r
> mydat

X Y

1 1.74 0

2 1.90 0

3 1.91 0

4 1.97 1

5 2.02 1

6 2.27 0

7 2.32 1

8 2.39 0

9 2.42 0

10 3.07 0

> lr1 = glm ( Y ~X , data = mydat , family = binomial ( link = logit ))

> summary ( lr1 )

Coefficients :

Estimate Std . Error z value Pr ( >| z |)

( Intercept ) 1.741 4.754 0.366 0.714

X -1.194 2.202 -0.542 0.588

> influence . measures ( lr1 )

Influence measures of

glm ( formula = Y ~ X , family = binomial ( link = logit ) , data = mydat ) :

dfb .1 _ dfb . X dffit cov . r cook . d hat inf

1 -0.5825 0.5258 -0.675 1.418 0.2232 0.303

2 -0.2805 0.2359 -0.397 1.301 0.0772 0.177

3 ?????? ?????? -0.386 1.296 0.0728 0.171

4 0.3203 -0.2515 0.547 0.962 0.1780 0.142

5 0.2426 -0.1736 0.511 0.935 0.1586 0.124

6 0.0613 -0.0955 -0.244 1.302 0.0281 0.116

7 -0.2203 0.2995 0.596 0.826 0.2346 0.128

8 0.1368 -0.1700 -0.272 1.369 0.0342 0.150

9 0.1548 -0.1878 -0.281 1.391 0.0366 0.162

10 0.5586 -0.5949 -0.628 2.496 0.1709 0.526
```

but after solving(by hand) using the formulas of DFBETAS and DFFITS for logistic regression
the answers where different from the answers of running the function influence.measures
I'm sure that there is nothing wrong with the calculations,
So I wonder how does the function influence.measures actually calculates DFBETAS and DFFITS?

Answer (score 0):

You can just type the function to see how it was calculated.  The line for the `dfbetas` columns is

```
dfbetas <- cf/outer(infl$sigma, sqrt(diag(xxi)))
```

Look earlier in the function for the calculations that compute `cf`, `infl`, and `xxi`.  You'll probably need to spend a while reading help pages `?outer`, `?diag`, and the functions used in the earlier calculations.

You can use `stats:::dfbetas.lm` to see a more compact version of the same calculation.